# how to get radio buttons in angular5 from mongodb

Tags: javascript, angular, html

In my Database i save gender, male="yes" In place of true i saved 'yes'. I am getting some other fields including gender to frontend in 'x' array. Now i want to show the gender with checked. I tried but not getting. can someone please help.

> html

```
<div class="radio">
                    <input type="radio" [value]="gender.male" name="gender" checked="getradio()">Male
                        <input type="radio" [value]="gender.female" name="gender" checked="getradio()">Female
                    </div>
```

> TS

```
getradio(){
 let checked=false;
  if(this.x[0].gender=='yes'){
checked=true
  }else{
    alert("not working")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your getradio() function should return true or false and in order to evaluate this function you should place 'checked' in a square brackets: `[checked]="getradio()"`